# which magento API using for create a new account

Tags: api, app

we are devoloping a android app for magento site.

we want to know where api s are calling in magento code.

for example : for creating an account, customer will enter every information

and click on "submit" button, suppose if there is already a customer registered with same email id ,

again new customer can not able to create with the account with the same email id.

what i want is how it works? which API magento using to check whether that email is already registered or not.

means which API it is passing to database to get information about that email id is registered or not.

let me know if you have any queries.

please help me to find solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

// If somestuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$result = $client->call($session, 'customer.info', '2');
var_dump($result);

// If you don't need the session anymore
//$client->endSession($session);
```

For more info [Click here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.html)

Comment: please inform me about path of the code....

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 this is API call ,,this code in present in above link